# Connection problem between React project and express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GAuP.png)

First, the folder structure is as above. 'App.js' and 'setupProxy.js' are in the src folder of the client folder.

The problem is that when I connect to localhost:3000 , the screen I expect does not appear. I thought I wrote some code that prints to the console the value of "test" of an object with key "test" and value "hi" , but that doesn't work. (The code is written below.)

[The browser screen I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCFbJ.png)
↑ The browser screen I want

[Actual browser screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gccT3.png)
↑ Actual browser screen

The screen for localhost:3000 is just the same as for localhost:5000.
Below I've attached the code I think you'll need to give you an answer.

[ client > src > App.js ]

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const callApi = async () => {
    axios.get("/").then((res) => console.log(res.data.test))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    callApi()
  }, [])

  return <div>test</div>
}

export default App
```

[ client > src > setupProxy.js ]

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware")

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware("/", {
            target: "http://localhost:5000",
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    )
}
```

[ server > Router > test.js ]

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ test: "hi" })
});

module.exports = router
```

[ server > server.js ]

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const test = require('./Router/test')

app.use('/', test)

const PORT = 5000
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

If I change the '/' path of 'App.js', 'setupProxy.js', and 'server.js' to a different path such as '/api', it works normally. Can't I use the '/' path like in my code? Then why...?
It may seem like a question that lacks basic knowledge, but I would be grateful if you could answer it.

Comment: The way express works, I believe, is that if you have multiple functions to the same route without any way to differentiate, like how you have it both on "/". Express will pick up the first function registered which seems like the json response. You could just leave them both as separate ports instead of targeting 5000 or add the "/api" to the backend since that's a normal convention.

Comment: @JosephNguyen Ah... So, the screens of localhost:3000 and localhost:5000 appear the same because express has no way to distinguish the '/' path? I'm not sure if I understood correctly... thank you so much for your reply!!

Comment: @JosephNguyen I also thought that the front-end and the back-end were separated by port numbers 3000 and 5000, respectively, but wouldn't it be meaningless if all paths were set to '/'... T.T

Comment: Yea it would be meaningless to set them all on "/" so when you create your paths you have to make sure it all routes differently. That's part of the reason why prepending "/api" is a convention to separate similar routes from the ui and api. You have to also becareful to not have variable paths before hard coded paths because then the variable paths might be the catch all. If you like my comments could you upvote them please. Sorry for shameless asking for upvotes haha.

Comment: @JosephNguyen I think I understand thanks to you. Upvote means to press the arrow next to it, right? Thanks so much for the reply!